# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' when trying to update a doc

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to post my python script on google cloud functions, but keep getting an error. I am getting an error when trying to update a field in a firestore document. Here's my code

```
driverDB = driverDB = db.collection('drivers')
driverList = []
for doc in driverDB.get():
    driverList.append(doc.id)

for driver in range(0,len(driverList)):
    routeDataDict = {
       'route':routeByDriverDict[driver]
    }
   
    driverDB.document(driverList[driver]).update(routeDataDict)
```

routeByDriverDict[driver] also returns a nested dictionary.

So I am trying to pass that routeDataDict to firestore. For this, I get the following error:

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py", line 272, in __init__ raise ValueError(error) ValueError: One or more components is not a string or is empty.
```

Not sure how to fix the situation. The update command doesn't seem to let me post a dictionary (even though it lets me do that in my jupyter notebook). I printed out the driverList[driver] and it correctly prints the doc ID, and routeDataDict correctly prints a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'route': {'stop_1': {'name': 'Christa Bauer',
   'address': '1980 Jay Street, Lakewood, CO 80214',
   'phone': 3039106747,
   'email': 'test@test.com',
   'has_reusables': False,
   'notes': None,
   'zone': 1,
   'leg_url': 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir//39.7471041,-105.0647146',
   'seconds_until_arrival': 360.0,
   'completed': False,
   'num_containers_at_this_stop': 0},
  'pay': '$50',
  'partner': 'burger_hut',
  'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 24, 1, 7, 1, 90282)}}
```

The entire error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.functions-framework/functions-framework/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 66, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 282, in routeCreatorMain driverDB.document('Lu2qHfOqtma48r7L2g4PsEDQizD2').update({'route':routeByDriverDict[driver]}) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", 
line 284, in update batch, kwargs = self._prep_update(field_updates, option, retry, timeout) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_document.py", 
line 232, in _prep_update batch.update(self, field_updates, option=option) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_batch.py", 
line 126, in update write_pbs = _helpers.pbs_for_update( File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 847, in pbs_for_update extractor = DocumentExtractorForUpdate(field_updates) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py",
 line 798, in __init__ super(DocumentExtractorForUpdate, self).__init__(document_data) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 422, in __init__ for field_path, value in iterator: File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 369, in extract_fields for s_path, s_value in extract_fields(value, field_path): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 369, in extract_fields for s_path, s_value in extract_fields(value, field_path): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 364, in extract_fields sub_key = FieldPath(key) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py",
 line 272, in __init__ raise ValueError(error) ValueError: One or more components is not a string or is empty.
```

Comment: Are you sure `db.document(driver)` is correct? Is your database correctly initialized and is `driver` really a string? And revert back to using `db.document(driver).update(routeDataDict)`.

Comment: Yes driver is correct, I tested that by printing it out and it prints out properly. the db is correct because I earlier do some document reads from the same db instance and it works.

Comment: So I don't have to do a JSON for the update? I can just do a normal dict? I don't know what else the issue would be.

Comment: and i should also clarify, db is really a connection to a collection, which is why I'm calling .document on it.

Comment: Yes it needs a dict for the update method. Maybe you could post some more code. All I can get from this line `File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py", line 272, in __init__ raise ValueError(error) ValueError: One or more components is not a string or is empty.` is that you access a field / document wrong.

Comment: @nils thanks, I added more detail to my code if that helps. When I print out the driverList[driver], it correctly prints the ID of the document for that driver. And also this same code works in my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Is there any chance for whole error stack?

Comment: I've updated it with the entire stack

Comment: I would think the problem is that `driverList[driver]` is not a string value, as it was suggested on the beginning. This will return such error. You said earlier that you have "printed it out" however you use print with int 1 and string "1" you will not see any difference. Better test it with `print(type(driverList[driver]))` to ensure that you get `str`

Comment: When I print it out i get class str

Comment: @vitooh When I pass in a test dictionary to the update command on the driverList[driver] doc, it works perfectly fine. The problem is not in driverList[driver]

Comment: Maybe the problem is in Cloud Function? Can you add how do you add this code to cloud function?